# in ag-grid community edition, how do you get the column menu icon to work as expected

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Using vue3 and ag-grid community edition,  when I click on the column menu icon, the text-filter menu does not pop up and the whole grid starts flashing. There are no errors in the console.

Browsers: Chrome and Edge

Modules:

- "ag-grid-community": "^29.2.0",
- "ag-grid-vue3": "^29.2.0",
- ...
- "vue": "^3.2.47",
- "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
- "vuetify": "^3.1.13"

Code:

```
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>

<script>
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AgGridVue,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Make", field: "make", filter: true },
        { headerName: "Model", field: "model",  },
        { headerName: "Price", field: "price" },
      ],
      rowData: [
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000 },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I also tried it out by adding it in the DOM without using ag-grid-vue3 and I still saw the issue.

My expectations are based on this page of the doc, which says that the text-filter functionality should be available in the community edition: https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/filter-text/

I gave this code a try too. This is straight from the sandbox, where it works. The sandbox uses vue ^3.0.0-0 so I am wondering if the version of vue is the problem.

```
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
    :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
      rowSelection="multiple"
    animateRows="true"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>

<script>
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AgGridVue,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
        { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
        { headerName: "Price", field: "price" },
      ],
      rowData: [
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
      ],
      defaultColDef : {
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      flex: 1
      }
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. When you create a new vue-3 hello-world application using vite's default setup, you get a base.css file with it. The file contains the following css rule, which breaks the ag-grid filter popup. Removing the rule from base.css fixed the problem:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```